# Игра виде парс биткоинта (ошибка)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, requests

В чем проблема цикл весь нормально проходит в конце не записывает пишет ошибку.Как исправить?

```
f = open()
line = f.readlines()
    for ide in line:
        address = ide
        r = requests.get('https://chain.so/api/v2/address/BTC/{}'.format(address))
        q = print('Address: {} Balance: {}'.format(address, (json.loads(r.content)['data']['balance'])))
        print(q)
    Write_data = open('Regular2_ball.txt', 'a')
    Write_data.writelines(q)
    Write_data.close()
```

еще есть вот такой код:

```
f = open()
line = f.readlines()
    for ide in line:
        address = ide
        r = requests.get('https://chain.so/api/v2/address/BTC/{}'.format(address))
        q = print('Address: {} Balance: {}'.format(address, (json.loads(r.content)['data']['balance'])))
        print(q)
if ('Address: {} Balance: {}'.format( (json.loads(r.content)['balance'])))<0:
print("none")
else:
    Write_data = open('Regular2_ball.txt', 'a')
    Write_data.writelines(q)
    Write_data.close()
```

`Ошибка такая: Address: 1Mqms3UrD1j7vHDEwRZ353rhmhNqWX6CgC Balance: 0.00000000 None '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'writeline'`
Как исправить?????

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос полный стек с ошибкой (кнопка [edit]), а то непонятно по каким строкам код выполнялся и в какой именно произошла та ошибка

Comment: Не нужно менять суть вопроса после того, как вам дали ответ - это автоматически делает ответ неправильным. Если у вас возник новый вопрос, задайте его отдельно. Если ответ помог, не забудьте его отметить принятым - для этого поставьте галку слева от ответа.

Comment: Так дали еще пару вопросов задать так бы и неменял бы тему если она не была б мертвой .Я уже успел триста раз улутшить код правда там ошибка образовалась новая.Ну ладно а как тогда спросить что за ошибка в ткинторе ?Сижу над дним уже третий день.Создать дубликаты твины профиля?

Answer (score 2):

Судя по ошибке:

```
_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'writeline'
```

У вас в коде на самом деле вместо реально существующей функции `writelines`, написана функция `writeline` (без завершающей `s`). Поэтому выходит ошибка. Проверьте код, который вы запускаете.